# Can you use a list or other iterable as input for a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a function that takes an arbitrary number of variables via the *args feature. Now another function needs to call this original function using a list of varying length, but I can't seem to find a solution. As a simplified example:

```
def print_all(*args):
    for x in args:
        print(x)

print_all([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Running this, the console displays:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

But I would like it to display:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there a way to turn an iterable like this into proper input for a function that accepts *args like above?

Answer (score 3):

The following will do the trick:

```
print_all(*[1,2,3,4,5])
```

With the star operator every item in the list is like been passed as a separate argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*` which exists in the parameter part of the function definition. Here `*` is unnecessary.

```
def print_all(args):
    for x in args:
        print(x)
```

Comment: This is true for my example, but my actual function is more complicated and I need to use *. Thanks for the answer though.